# DocuSign envelope Redirect URL to another DocuSign session is not working

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, docusignapi, asp.net-core-webapi

We had this implementation in place where we created two envelopes in our API and added 1st envelope's URI at the place of second envelope's redict URI and it was working fine till September 23 but then the redirection from one envelope to another envelope stopped working.

Here's the explanation with the Code:

```
 RecipientViewRequest financeManagerViewOptions = new RecipientViewRequest
            {
                ReturnUrl = returnViewURL,
                ClientUserId = "Finance12345",
                AuthenticationMethod = "none",
                UserName = FinanceManagerName,
                Email = FinanceManagerEmail
            };

            //this is the second envelope, and we used this envelope's URL as the returnURL of the second envelope
            financeManagerviewUrl = docusignAPI.CreateRecipientView(AccountId, result.EnvelopeId, financeManagerViewOptions);

            //here we are creating the second envelope and assigning the first envelope's URL to its returnURL
            RecipientViewRequest viewOptions = new RecipientViewRequest
            {
                ReturnUrl = financeManagerviewUrl.Url,
                ClientUserId = inspection.CustomerId.ToString(),
                AuthenticationMethod = "none",
                UserName = inspection.CustomerName,
                Email = inspection.CustomerEmail,
            };

            // url of second evelope that is supposed to be signed first
            viewUrl = docusignAPI.CreateRecipientView(AccountId, result.EnvelopeId, viewOptions);
```

now the weird thing over here is that if we directly open the first envelope URL in the browser it works fine and it also redirects us to a correct URL, so the return URL for the first envelope also works fine.

but when we redirect our second envelope to our first envelope's URL it shows us this error which is weird for us:

[image]

Again, this was working fine a few days back and opening the first envelope's URL directly in the browser let us do the signing but the same URL in return URL doesn't open the new signing session, Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed Tokens is a new approach we are taking to urls to envelopes.
It makes the url way longer which is probably the root cause of your issue.
We are enabling this feature for various accounts throughout this month and this is probably what happened to you recently.
You would have to figure out a different approach to your integration if the url is too long.

Comment: Thanks for responding to the problem timely, we wrote a new implementation for this. Could you please guide me towards some portal where we can stay updated with DocuSign changes? as this is a business-critical part of our application and its failure breaks a very important flow in the application.

Comment: this was a one-off if you will. Not something that happens very often. The portal is developers.docusign.com as well as support.docusign.com (different focus). Let me know if I can help further.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I appreciate all the help.